# React navigation "replace" the previous 2 screens instead of only 1

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

In react navigation, how can I replace the last two screens in a stack?

For example, if my current stack is `screen1 -> screen2 -> screen3`, when I call `.replace('screen4')` on screen3,
it becomes `screen1 -> screen2 -> screen4`

But I want a way so it becomes `screen1 -> screen4`

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use `reset` to do it:

```js
import { CommonActions } from "@react-navigation/native";

// ...

navigation.dispatch(state => {
  // Remove the last 2 routes from current list of routes
  const routes = state.routes.slice(0, -2);

  // Reset the state to the new state with updated list of routes
  return CommonActions.reset({
    ...state,
    index: routes.length - 1,
    routes
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

Scroll down for solution

## Long answer

I find @satya164 to be a bit confusing, because the provided piece of code will actually remove the last two screens and simply push you back, unless you go on to push another screen using `navigation.push` or `navigation.navigate`.

So the actual solution would be:

```js
import {CommonActions, StackActions} from '@react-navigation/native';

// this removes last two screens
navigation.dispatch(state => {
      const routes = state.routes.slice(0, -2);


      return CommonActions.reset({
        ...state,
        index: routes.length - 1,
        routes,
      });

      // can also be replaced by:
      // return StackActions.popToTop();
    });

// and pushes a new one directly
navigation.navigate('YourNewScreen', { /* optional params */ });
```

But even then, at least on `iOS` the animation will go backwards, as if a screen is being popped (i.e: user going backwards), instead of being pushed, which isn't very intuitive, and looks a bit weird.

I found that if you want to navigate to a new stacked screen, but want to discard the rest of the stack. The best way to do that, is to navigate to the needed screen, and to discard the rest of the screens keeping the first and last one (the one being presented) after the navigation has happened. This way, yo get the desired behavior and there are no weird jumps or wrong navigations animations.

Another plus is that this way you don't care how many screens you got in between, you just take the first and last. You can then put it in a neat little generic hook:

### Solution

```js
import {CommonActions} from '@react-navigation/native';

// call this hook in the last screen of the stack (so `screen4`)
export const useResetNavigationStackEffect = (props, condition) => {
  const {navigation} = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (condition) { // only reset if `true`
      navigation.dispatch(state => {
        const topScreen = state.routes[0];
        const thisScreen = state.routes[state.routes.length - 1];
        const routes = [topScreen, thisScreen];
        return CommonActions.reset({
          ...state,
          index: routes.length - 1,
          routes,
        });
      });
    }
  }, [condition, navigation]);
};
```